# What is the burette solution called in a titration, when its concentration is unknown?

Tags: terminology, titration

Generally in titration, the unknown solution is in the conical flask, called the analyte; the standard solution is in the burette, called the titrant. How do the terminologies change when one swaps the contents in the burette and the conical flask?

Is the solution in the burette always called the titrant? Or is titrant the solution with known concentration?

Answer (score 3):

There is no fundamental requirement in analytical chemistry that the unknown or the known solution is in the burette. *Traditionally*, the standard solution is filled in the burette. All we need is the correct volume of unknown and the known (called a standard) to perform calculations.

The reagent (known or unknown concentration) being added to a receiving solution is called the titrant. The receiving solution is called the titran**d**. The latter term is commonly used as a jargon but it is not an accepted word in leading English dictionaries (Websters, Oxford etc.).